# How would I make this valid xml?

Tags: c++, xml, rapidxml

```
<entry key="<div class="private">([\n](.)*)*</div>"> </entry>
```

I need to parse this with **rapidxml**, and I cannot seem to escape those inner quotes with a backslash. How can I make this valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML does not use backslashes.

Instead, it uses entities: `&quot;`

Comment: so `&quot;private&quot;` ?

Comment: Don't forget the angle brackets. `<entry key="&lt;div class=&quot;private&quot;&gt;([\n](.)*)*&lt;/div&gt;"> </entry>` - try here. http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Comment: @Roddy Cool, thanks. I didn't even think of escaping the greater than - less than signs for some reason.